# When you call a bluff and are wrong, how is the card that dies chosen?

Tags: coup

In Coup, if you don't believe someone has a card, you can call them out and they must reveal a card. If that card isn't the one they've said it is, it dies.

However, if it is, one of yours dies.

How is that card chosen?

Comment: Nit: They *may* reveal a card. They need not reveal the card even if they have it; they may simply take the hit in order to keep the card.

Comment: @ikegami That is a very important part and can be a key strategy for winning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You choose the card.

Comment: This is right, although you don't actually discard you just reveal.

Comment: @ConMan, It's not just revealed; it's removed from play

Comment: @ikegami In this case discarding is a bad term since it should remain in front of the player as a reminder to everyone of what has been lost.

Comment: @ikegami When I think of discard it brings to mind a pile of cards where you will not see all the cards that have been discarded rather then just placing the card in front of you face up.

Comment: @ikegami I must just be lucky to play a lot of games with common discard piles then. :)

Comment: @ikegami The card stays in front of you so it is not really discarding it.

Comment: I have no problem with the idea that discarded cards need not be common, I think it's more that to discard tends to suggest throwing the card away, whereas in Coup when you lose an influence the card stays where it is, but is just turned face up. There's probably also the fact that, to my knowledge, the rules never refer to lost influence being "discarded".

Comment: @ConMan, The card *is* throw away. Again, you don't just reveal the card. It can no longer be used.

Comment: Maybe bypass all the debate and just say "turn face-up", the same terminology as the rules? They say "...you lose an influence, turning one of your characters face-up. Face-up characters cannot be used, and if both of your characters are face-up, you're out of the game." And it's kind of important that it's still there face-up, as opposed to being entirely out of the game - people can see what it was and use that to help guess about what other people might have.

Comment: @Jefromi, It's far too much information, and far too little. How you discard is of no importance to the question or answer (the OP already knows what to do after he chooses the card), and that only partially explains the action (it's not just placed face-up; it's removed from play).

Comment: Still, it's often helpful and less confusing to use the same language as the rules - as you imply, the OP also knows what a face-up card means in the context of the game. But up to you, of course.

Comment: @ikegami As you saw in the comments, not everyone understands that standard gaming term in quite the same way as you (some people think "discard" means it needs to physically go somewhere else), so using it created confusion. On the other hand, using the same terminology as the rules tends not to create confusion; not everyone shares your view that calling it "turn face-up" is not a name and inherently wrong and thus confusing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22849/discussion-between-jefromi-and-ikegami).